# Can prism know even data outside the US Data centers?

Tags: privacy, nsa

I would like to know whether the US Prism can know even the data outside of the US Data centers.

For example, If I have my own servers and all the data in Indian servers but I have been using some services like web application acceleration, security, domain name registration etc from US companies, then is there a chance of US Prism knowing my data?

Answer (score 5):

Anyone who *really* knows the answer to this question is either prohibited from telling you or is a political refugee in Russia.  I think it's pretty good bet that any data that passes through any one of the "Five Eyes" nations (GBR, USA, CAN, AUS, and NZL) *could* be captured.  And, of course, other governments could be doing the same sort of thing.

Comment: Is there any chance, if a buy a domain name from an US registrar?

Comment: Think about where the *data* go.  Unless your domain registrar is also your web host, which is not the case, since you say your host is in India, then no.  But the web accelerator?  Yes, because the web accelerator sees the data.

Comment: So, I'll need to do the entire stuff in my country and release non-sensitive ones like static files to a CDN service in US?

Comment: You could do that.  However, unless you are trying to be Silk Road 3.0, you could just not worry about it.  In any case, focus on where the *data* go.

Comment: No matter even if the data is highly encrypted, can it be seen by Prism? Because credit card information is confidential and must not be seen!

Comment: The comments aren't really a place for extended discussions, so this will be my last one.  Yes, if data passes through the Five Eyes nations, even encrypted, it can (potentially) be captured.  The next question is whether it can be decrypted, and I have no idea.  The U.S. NSA is rumored to have half the world's total computing power.

Comment: @JavaTechnical the NSA getting credit card numbers would be the least of my worries... they have nothing to do with CC numbers, they want conversations, personal data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the disclosures from other countries, you can see that countries could/can elect to provide data in response to requests from the NSA. That places it "in scope" of PRISM, so, technically, yes, PRISM can see data outside of US Data Centers, it's just not designed to (according to the info leaked).

Any data flowing through US data services (including web acceleration) is under PRISM's scope.

You suggest in a comment that you are concerned about credit card data being viewed by PRISM. I'm not sure that this is a type of data that you need to protect. It is possible for the US to obtain that data through other means.